# Basic set inclusion in a metric space

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, self-learning

Consider the sets $A$ and $B$ in a metric space $(E,d)$. Clearly $A\cap B \subseteq B$. Suppose $closure(A\cap B) \neq B$. Then $closure(A\cap B) \subset B$ or $closure(A\cap B)  \supset B$. My intuition says the latter is not possible. How to argue about it?

*A closure point $x$ of $A$ is such that all open ball centered in $x$ has a nonempty intersection with $A$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot argue about it, since it is false. Suppose that your metric space is $\mathbb R$, endowed with its usual distance. Take $A=[0,1]$ and $B=\mathbb Q$. Then $\overline{A\cap B}=A$ and therefore neither $\overline{A\cap B}\subset B$ nor $\overline{A\cap B}\subset B$ hold.

Comment: What if I impose B is open set in the metric space?

Comment: That is another question. I suggest that you post it as such.

Comment: $\overline{A \cap B} = A$,  Why?

Comment: Because $A=[0,1]$ and for every $x\in[0,1]$ there are rational points of $[0,1]$ arbitrarily close to it.